# Finding most commonly coincident values within an array with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to display the most commonly ordered pairs of products for a set of orders placed. an abbreviated version of my search index would look something like this:

```
{
    "_type" : "order",
    "_id" : "10",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
        ...
        "product_ids" : [
            1, 2
        ]
        ...
    }
},
{
    "_type" : "order",
    "_id" : "11",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
        ...
        "product_ids" : [
            1, 2, 3
        ]
        ...
    }
}
```

Given that my search index contains a set of orders, each with a `product_ids` field that contains an array of the product ids that are in the order, is it possible to put together an Elasticsearch aggregation that will return either:

1. The most common pairs of product ids (which may be members of an arbitrarily long list of product ids) that occur the most frequently together in orders.
2. The most common sets of product ids of an arbitrary length that occur most frequently together in orders.

I've been reading the documentation, and I'm not sure if an adjacency matrix might be appropriate for this problem. My current hunch is to write a scripted cardinality query that orders and joins the `product_ids` in the search document to get results in line with #2, since #1 seems like it might involve too many permutations of product ids to be reasonably efficient.

Comment: using elasticsearch composite aggs with two array fields listed in the aggs sources is my solution to my similar problems  . https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html